# Can I use a Shure Beta 58 vocal mic with my PowerBook MacIntosh laptop?

Tags: microphone

I have an older Shure Beta 58 mic purchased in 1996 that I would like to use as an external microphone in lieu of th built in mic on my PowerBook laptop.  What interface do I need?  I would like to use it for conferencing software like Zoom.  I am also supposed to make an audio recording of some songs to send to a virtual choir project.

Answer (score 1):

An XLR (the connector on the Shure mic) to USB audio device is what you need. There are several varieties on the market, but this is a very handy gadget which has worked well for me.

[Shure X2U XLR to USB USB Signal Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001PPXFAG)